# Can I use Unity to build games for the KaiOS platform?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, firefox-os, gecko, kaios

**[KaiOS](https://www.kaiostech.com/)** is "a web-based mobile operating system that is based on Linux kernel forked from B2G (Boot to Gecko), an open source community-driven successor of **Firefox OS** which was discontinued by Mozilla in 2016. (As written on its [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KaiOS))

I wanted to use Unity Game Engine to make a game for it but I have not seen KaiOS as one of the available platforms to build for.

**Is it possible that one of the platforms that Unity builds for (such as HTML5) can be made somehow compatible for KaiOS?** Are there any other available tools I can use? Or will I have to work on the raw game from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityCloudBuildSupportedPlatforms.html

Sorry to be a let down. It does support iOS though.

**EDIT**

If you put a little more work into it using HTML5, then yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vakore. I know that Unity doesn't officially support KaiOS. I was wondering if Is was possible that one of the platforms that Unity does support (such as HTML5) can be made somehow compatible for KaiOS with a little more work?

Comment: Oh, in that case yes.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what kind of "more work" could be required?

Comment: Not specifically. You'd need to make some sort of extenstion to make it compatible with KaiOS or figure out what KaiOS can/can't handle.